# Is it possible to make a custom sort on column other than A-Z or Z-A in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

The Sheet has a column with cells populated by a dropdown list offering 3 choices: Good; Very Good; Rejected;

In that context, it would be practical to sort the column according to a specific/custom order on those 3 values, no matter the alphabetic order.

E.g.: Rejected in first, Very Good in second and Good in last.

Filter offers only A-Z or Z-A. Is there a way to decide the order base on values in a column?

Comment: You could use a hidden helper column with a single array formula that will help you do this. If you'd like to share a link to your sheet or a copy of your sheet, I'll devise the solution, implement it, and explain it here.

Comment: Yep it seems like the solution. I was asking to see if there was another way. I had made a new sheet with a fake « Table » using Key/Value pair mimicking a Database with index, but I endup playing with a hidden column in the main sheet so I was hoping to find a more standard way of doing that sort, but I realise it's probably not possible.

Answer (score 0):

An trivial way to solve this is to change the names of your categories to '1-Rejected', '2-Very Good' and '3-Good'.

Comment: Hi Oren! I had that idea too. I played with a number at the begining or end of the category with a white font so it was invisible. Quite nice, but the format is lost when exported in  Google Docs Table. But thanks, good tip!

Comment: If exporting is an issue, you can then create a simple script that replaces all "Very Good" by "2-Very Good", sort, and then replace it back.